# Matching Text Between A Repeat Tag Pattern

Tags: text, matching

If I have this text "/text1/text2/text3/endtag" & want to extract the last text (text3) before the endtag, what is the regex pattern I would need to use?

I tried this:

```
 /\/(.*)\// &
```

that gave me everything before endtag.

Following gave me only "text1"

```
/\/(.*?)\//
```

I'm a novice when it comes to regex so thanks in advance for your help & patience.

Answer (score 1):

```
var matches = /([^\/]*)\/endtag$/.exec("/text1/text2/text3/endtag");
console.log(matches[1]);
```

You want to match a string of characters that does not contain a "/" followed by "/endtag" plus end of line.